# updating a table with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I created a **time in** and **time out** system. Here is the table

> time table

```
| id | time id | time in | time out |
|  1 |    1    | 1:00 am |          |
|  1 |    2    | 1:013am |          |
```

**id** is a foreign key while the **time id** is a *time table* primary key. How can i update the timeout table?

Here is my code in **time in**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$timein = date('Y/m/d H.i.s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO time (id, timein)
        VALUES
        ('$id','$timein')
";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

if(is_resource($query) and mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row["id"];
    }
echo $sql;
```

which is correct, but my question is how can I update the **time out**?

This will target the certain time id, for example time id 1. But I also want to update **time out**.

I already tried something like this

```
$timeid = $_SESSION['timeid'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$timein = $_POST['timein'];
$timeout = date('Y/m/d H.i.s');

$sql = "UPDATE time SET(time_id, id, timein, timeout)
        VALUES
        ('$time_id','$id','$timein','$timeout') WHERE id = $id
";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

if(is_resource($query) and mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row["id"];
    }
echo $sql;
```

and this is the code is use to view the context of time in and time out so how can i get the exact timeid to edit it?

```
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['time_id']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['timein']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['timeout']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['totalmin']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><a href= \"timeout.php?id=".$row['time_id']." \"> timeout";
echo "</tr>";
```

the update is ok thanks to MAWIA but when i update only one timeid will get updated

Comment: Just do where one thing equals another thing. Your question isn't phrased very well at all.

Comment: @Kisaragi im trying to say is is their anyway i can create a time out? or i just need to update the time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a timeout, I think you don't need to update time_id, id and timein because you already insert in your first statement. So your update statement would be:

```
   $checkFk = mysql_query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");//turn off foreign key
   $sql = "UPDATE `time` SET `timeout`='$timeout' WHERE `timeid` = '$timeid'";
   $resetFk = mysql_query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1");//turn on foreign key
```

Don't use mysql extension Please look at [mysql improved extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: so that area just i need to edit? how about the $_POST?

Comment: since it's unclear how you get your data. You are using GET and POST. So in your form from where you do the update, is the method='POST' which in fact is a better approach. And you can grab the data by $_REQUEST which accepts both GET and POST data.

Comment: but i have a foreign key sir in time table but didnt update

Comment: i didnt use a form in time in just automatically insert time because it is a current time stamp

Comment: You can turn off foreign key constraint using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` and if you are updating it using session timeout, it's fine.

Comment: it updated sir thnx but there is still a problem in just one id it update not the other timeid

Comment: If you want to update multiple rows, you have to put them in loop.

Comment: $id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
//$_SESSION['time_id'] = $row['time_id'];
echo "<td><center>".$row['time_id']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['timein']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['timeout']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['totalmin']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><a href= \"timeout.php?id=".$row['time_id']." \"> timeout";
echo "</tr>";