# TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTES, $foo1, $foo2) didnt display

Tags: php, mysql

regarding in this question [timein and timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063680/updating-a-table-with-foreign-key/36064463?noredirect=1#comment59777714_36064463)

how can post the difference of this two time?

i already tried this one at **timeout.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
session_start();

$timeid = $_GET['id'];
$timeout = date('Y-m-d H.i.s');

$sql = "UPDATE time SET timeout = '$timeout', totalmin = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '$timein','$timeout') WHERE time_id = '$timeid'
";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

if(is_resource($query) and mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row["id"];
    }
echo $sql;

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

also this one at **timein.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';


$id = $_GET['id'];
$timein = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$timeout = '';

$sql = "INSERT INTO time (id, timein, timeout, totalmin)
        VALUES
        ('$id','$timein','','')
";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

if(is_resource($query) and mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row["id"];
    }
echo $sql;

header('Location: employee.php?id='.$id);
?>
```

by the way im using a current_time stamp in time in and timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You're using improper time formats:

```
$timeout = date('Y-m-d H.i.s');
                        ^^^
```

MySQL's date/time-as-string format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, aka. `Y-m-d h:i:s` - use colons, not periods.

And note that there is pretty much NO point in having PHP generate this date string anyways. MySQL can do that for you already anyways:

```
  ... VALUES($id, now(), etc...)
                  ^^^^^
```

As well, note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: its ok im doing it for project in school and it is urgent gonna submit it tomorrow

Comment: i didnt get ur suggestion sir in this one ... VALUES($id, now(), etc...)
                  ^^^^^

Comment: i mean how can i get the timediff of the timein and timeout?